# Trying to understand why sed emulating rev loops on same line until all reversed

Tags: sed

```
sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'
```

Above command reverses line and emulates rev.
But as per my understanding, sed is a line editor and it executes all actions seperated by ; on one line then reads second line.

So in above line why even after executing all commands one time it keeps looping until all characters are reversed.??

I dont want to understand how commad works i know that. But **why after executing all action seperated by ; once it keeps executing until all characters reverse**
**Why loop kind of behaviour**
I can't understand this behaviour

eg.
`echo 'Hey i am fine' | sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'`
Should be :
Pattern space

```
-->(1st action) Hey i am fine\n 
--> (2nd action) Hey i am fine\ney i am fine\nH
-->(3rd action) ey i am fine\nH
-->(4th action) At this point it should execute s/.// and exit or read next line
```

But why after 3rd action 1st action is repeated

Seems like as long as patter space is not deleted the sed will not read next line and keep repeating cycle on same pattern space.

Seems like D option is doing this.

But But why after first D action s/.// is not executed but repeated from beginning.??

Comment: [This page](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one), list item 37, has a good explanation. If you have GNU sed, you can also run the command with `sed --debug` and watch what happens.

Comment: i dont want to know how command works. But even after one cycle means after s/.//; why it keeps repeating all actions on same line before reading another

Comment: Because, as the explanation for how the command works points out, `D` creates a loop.

Comment: And you can observe exactly that with `--debug`. You *do* want to understand how the command works, because that explains why it doesn't run every sed command just once.

Comment: But But why after first D action s/.// is not executed but repeated from beginning.??

Comment: Did you read what `D` command is doing? From `man sed` : `D      If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if the d command was issued.  Otherwise, delete  text  in  the  pattern
              space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.`. It has literally "restart cycle .. without reading ... input".

Comment: [GNU sed manual about `D`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-D-_0028delete-first-line_0029-command), [*Editing commands in sed* for POSIX sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03)

Comment: In essence `d`, `D` and `c` sed commands end the current sed cycle and disregard any following sed commands. As do `t`, `T` and `b` without a following argument.

Comment: If you want a mandatory POSIX command to emulate `rev`, just use awk: `awk '{rev=""; for (i=1;i<=length($0);i++) rev = substr($0,i,1) rev; print rev}'`. Clear, simple, robust, portable, etc. and you won't find yourself asking "Trying to understand why...." questions.